# python koans: class proxy

Tags: python, proxy-classes, setattr

I'm solving [the python koans](https://bitbucket.org/gregmalcolm/python_koans/wiki/Home).
I haven't got any real problem until the 34th.

this is the problem:

> ## Project: Create a Proxy Class
>
> In this assignment, create a proxy class (one is started for you
>   below).  You should be able to initialize the proxy object with any
>   object.  Any attributes called on the proxy object should be forwarded
>   to the target object.  As each attribute call is sent, the proxy
>   should record the name of the attribute sent.
>
> The proxy class is started for you.  You will need to add a method
>   missing handler and any other supporting methods.  The specification
>   of the Proxy class is given in the AboutProxyObjectProject koan.
>
> Note: This is a bit trickier that it's Ruby Koans counterpart, but you
>   can do it!

and this is my solution until now:

```
class Proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, target_object):
        self._count = {}
        #initialize '_obj' attribute last. Trust me on this!
        self._obj = target_object

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):pass


    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr in self._count: 
            self._count[attr]+=1
        else: 
            self._count[attr]=1
        return getattr(self._obj, attr)

    def messages(self):
        return self._count.keys()

    def was_called(self, attr):
        if attr in self._count:
            return True
        else: False

    def number_of_times_called(self, attr):
        if attr in self._count:
            return self._count[attr]
        else: return False
```

It works until this test:

```
def test_proxy_records_messages_sent_to_tv(self):
    tv = Proxy(Television())

    tv.power()
    tv.channel = 10

    self.assertEqual(['power', 'channel='], tv.messages())
```

where `tv.messages()` is `['power']` because `tv.channel=10` is taken by the proxy object and not the television object.
I've tried to manipulate the `__setattr__` method, but I always end in a unlimited loop.

#### edit 1:

I'm trying this:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if hasattr(self, name):
            object.__setattr__(self,name,value)
        else: 
            object.__setattr__(self._obj, name, value)
```

But then I get this error in a loop on the last entry:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object


File "/home/kurojishi/programmi/python_koans/python 2/koans/about_proxy_object_project.py", line 60, in test_proxy_method_returns_wrapped_object
tv = Proxy(Television())                                                                                                                                     
File "/home/kurojishi/programmi/python_koans/python 2/koans/about_proxy_object_project.py", line 25, in __init__                                               
self._count = {}                                                                                                                                             
File "/home/kurojishi/programmi/python_koans/python 2/koans/about_proxy_object_project.py", line 33, in __setattr__                                            
object.__setattr__(self._obj, name, value)                                                                                                                   
File "/home/kurojishi/programmi/python_koans/python 2/koans/about_proxy_object_project.py", line 36, in __getattr__                                            
if attr in self._count:
```

The loop is in `__getattr__`.

Comment: is the posted error complete ? what the exception is ?

Comment: sorry this is just a little of the error. the error loop on the last entry the exception is 'RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object'

Comment: did you get the chance to try my hint?

Comment: sadly no, i was a intense exame session i belive i'll have the time after september :)

Answer (score 6):

You are using `hasattr` in `__setattr__` to decide whether you should write to the local or proxied object. This works well for all but one case.

In your `__init__` you have the following line:

```
  self._count = {}
```

This calls `__setattr__` with `'_count'` which does not exist at that point and therefore (hence `hasattr` returns `False`) is forwarded to the proxied object.

If you want to use your approach you have to write your `__init__` like this:

```
def __init__(self, target_object):
    object.__setattr__(self, '_count', {})
    #initialize '_obj' attribute last. Trust me on this!
    object.__setattr__(self, '_obj', target_object)
```

Comment: thanks this seems to be a good solution, i'll try it in the first slice of freetime, thanks, same for the others, i've been very busy and i could not try the last ones, i'll check them as soon as possible, many thanks

Comment: did you have time to check? ;)

Comment: i'm slowing redoing all the koans(left the complete one home changing country and the pc was cut from the network).
i'll arrive to it :)

Answer (score 4):

As I understand maybe your problem is related with the recursive call when you set and attribute value. [From docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html):

If `__setattr__()` wants to assign to an instance attribute, it should not simply execute "`self.name = value`" -- this would cause a recursive call to itself. Instead, it should insert the value in the dictionary of instance attributes, e.g., "`self.__dict__[name] = value`". For new-style classes, rather than accessing the instance dictionary, it should call the base class method with the same name, for example, "`object.__setattr__(self, name, value)`".

Comment: edited with an initial idea using that methods. not working though

Answer (score 1):

setattr is called on all assignments. It's more like getattribute than getattr. This also affects code in the __init__ method.

This means that the first branch of this code will almost always fail, only attributes inherited from object will pass the test:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if hasattr(self, name):
        object.__setattr__(self,name,value)
    else: 
        object.__setattr__(self._obj, name, value)
```

Instead we
 can assume that assignments are meant for the Proxy unless it has an _obj attribute. Hence the comment in __init__. We set up our proxy's attributes, then add the target object and all future assignments get sent to it.

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if hasattr(self, '_obj'):
        object.__setattr__(self._obj, name, value)
    else:
        object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
```

But by using hasattr we would also need to alter __getattr__ to check for _obj to prevent recursion:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    if '_obj' == name:
        raise AttributeError

    if attr in self._count: 
        self._count[attr]+=1
    else: 
        self._count[attr]=1
    return getattr(self._obj, attr)
```

An alternative would be to inspect the proxy's __dict__ attribute directly in the __setattr__ method:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if '_obj' in self.__dict__:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

from the test, it is a requirement for proxy to log all the attribute calls via proxy. And the proxy has only few built-in methods which are exceptionally used for logging, so my answer was:

```
class Proxy(object):

    def __init__(self, target_object):
        self.logs=[]
        self._obj = target_object


    def __getattribute__(self, attrname):
        if attrname in ['_obj','logs','messages','was_called','number_of_times_called'] :
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attrname)
        else:
            self.logs.append(attrname)
            return object.__getattribute__((object.__getattribute__(self, '_obj')), attrname)


    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if hasattr(self, '_obj'):
            self.logs.append(name)
            object.__setattr__(object.__getattribute__(self,'_obj'), name, value)
        else :
            object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
```

After this it is quite easy to implement other methods ('messages', 'was_called', ... )

Sorry for necro'ing old question.

and I found out that **getattribute** can be changed : just check whether the attribute is in the target object.

```
def __getattribute__(self, attrname):
        if attrname not in dir(object.__getattribute__(self, '_obj')):
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attrname)
        else:
            self.logs.append(attrname)
            return object.__getattribute__((object.__getattribute__(self, '_obj')), attrname)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Proxy(object):
   """Proxy class wraps any other class, and adds functionality to remember and report all messages called.
Limitations include that proxy blocks all direct subclass calls to:
messages, number_of_times_called, was_called, _obj, and _message_counts.
These calls must be made directly like my_proxy_instance._obj.messages.
"""


def __init__(self, target_object):
    print 'initializing a proxy for ' + target_object.__class__.__name__
    # WRITE CODE HERE
    self._message_counts = Counter();
    #initialize '_obj' attribute last. Trust me on this!
    self._obj = target_object

# WRITE CODE HERE                                   
def  __getattr__(self, attr_name):
    print 'getting an attribute: "' + attr_name + '" from "' + self._obj.__class__.__name__  + '"'
    self._message_counts[attr_name] += 1
    print self._message_counts
    return object.__getattribute__(self._obj, attr_name)

#def __getattribute__(self, attr_name):
#    print "intercepted!~ " + attr_name
#    object.__getattribute__(self, attr_name)

def __setattr__(self, attr_name, value):
    if((attr_name == '_obj') | (attr_name == '_message_counts')): # special proxy attributes.
        print 'setting the PROXY attribute: "' + attr_name + '"'
        object.__setattr__(self, attr_name, value)
    else:
        print 'setting the REAL attribute: "' + attr_name + '"'
        self._message_counts[attr_name+"="] += 1
        object.__setattr__(self._obj, attr_name, value)

def messages(self):
    return self._message_counts.keys()

def number_of_times_called(self, attr_name):
    return self._message_counts[attr_name]

def was_called(self, attr_name):
    return attr_name in self._message_counts
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was take all the calls to attributes in the proxy and call them via `object.__getattribute__` to avoid recursion.

That did not work for methods so I wrapped the method calls in a try..except AttributeError to try them first in the proxy. and then if they raise an error try them in the child object.

If anyone has a more elegant solution would love to see it.

```
from runner.koan import *
from collections import Counter

class Proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, target_object):
        self._messages=[]
        self._obj = target_object

    def messages(self):
        return self._messages

    def was_called(self, message):
        return message in self._messages

    def number_of_times_called(self, message):
        _count = Counter(self._messages).get(message)
        if _count: 
            return _count
        else: # catch None
            return 0

    def __getattribute__(self, attr_name):
        try: # call on self
            retval = object.__getattribute__(self, attr_name)
        except AttributeError: # call on child object
            retval = self._obj.__getattribute__(attr_name)
            object.__getattribute__(self, '_messages').append(attr_name)

        return retval

    def __setattr__(self, attr_name, attr_value):
        if hasattr(self, '_obj'): # call child object and log message
            self._obj.__setattr__(attr_name, attr_value)
            attr_name += "="
            object.__getattribute__(self, '_messages').append(attr_name)
        else: # use this before_obj is set in __init__
            object.__setattr__(self, attr_name, attr_value)

    def messages(self):
        return self._messages
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use method_missing?
my answer:

```rb
class Proxy
  def initialize(target_object)
    @object = target_object
    # ADD MORE CODE HERE
    @messages = []
  end

  # WRITE CODE HERE
  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    @messages.push method_name unless method_name == :messages
    @object.send method_name, *args, &block
  end
  def messages
    @messages
  end
  def called? target
    @messages.include? target
  end
  def number_of_times_called target
    result = 0
    @messages.each do |t|
      result += 1 if t == target
    end
    result
  end
end
```